# Chrome Canary ignoring hosts mapping, Chrome stable works fine

Tags: google-chrome

I have custom domain mapping set in hosts, Google Chrome (39.0.2171.95) is using them just fine, but Google Chrome Canary (41.0.2267.0 canary) is just ignoring them.

Is there a good way how to debug this problem? Or better, how to solve it?

On OS X Yosemite (10.10.1 (14B25))